# Custom wpDataTables JS - positive and negative

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

hoping to get some help with my custome wpDataTables JS. This questions has been asked before - 'How to Colorize negative/positive numbers' and the answer was this link - 
http://www.alunr.com/articles/jquery-addclass-to-positive-and-negative-values-on-a-page - but I can't seem to apply it in my table. Can anyone help?

This is what I added
[printscreen - my custom js page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/arSL5.jpg)

Thanks so much!

Comment: Hi maksh, my table is pickup from a CSV file using the wpdatatables plugin. My table is here http://103.51.41.206/~hwangimc/aham/daily-fund-price/

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

1) in the Custom wpDataTables JS box, enter following:

```html
</script>
<script>
(function($) {
$('.numdata.uren_kolom').each(function() {
 var Uren = $(this).text();

 if ((Uren > 0) && (Uren < 6)) {
  $(this).addClass("laag");
 }
 else if((Uren > 5) && (Uren < 8)) {
  $(this).addClass("gemiddeld");
 }
 else {
  $(this).addClass("positive");
 }
});
})(jQuery);
```

2) In textbox "Custom wpDataTables CSS", enter following:

```css
.laag{color: red;}
.hoog{color: #22a000;}
.gemiddeld{color: #000000;}
```

3) in the column where you want conditional formatting, enter CSS class:

```css
uren_kolom
```

Comment: Worked great! I got some help and got it modified to this :
<script>
(function($) {
 $('.numdata').each(function() {
  var negative = $(this).text().indexOf('-') != -1,
   zero = $(this).text().indexOf('0.0000') != -1;
  if (!negative && !zero) {
   $(this).addClass("positive");
  } else if(zero)  {
   $(this).addClass("zero");
  } else {
   $(this).addClass("negative");
  }
 });
})(jQuery);
</script>